# VBA - Loop through range, copy to second sheet, save as, repeat

Tags: vba, loops

I have a list in Sheet2 (e.g. A:A). I want to copy each item into a cell in Sheet1 (e.g."A1"), save as a new workbook and continue through the list in sheet2. I need the loop to end once the list has been complete.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Only save sheet1 as new workbook or include sheet2?

Comment: Can you provide the code you've written and where the specific problem is occurring. To help us, you should take the [Stack Overflow Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Write a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  You'll get great help quickly.

Comment: Thanks - I've got this so far. Although I need a way to hardcode and delete all other sheets (apart from sheet1) before saving down...


`Sub generateWorkbooks()

Dim countries()
Dim i As Integer
Dim wkbk As String

wkbk = ActiveWorkbook.Path

countries = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value


For i = 1 To UBound(countries)
  
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = countries(i, 1)

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=wkbk & "\Example - " & CStr(countries(i, 1)), FileFormat:=52
    
Next
End Sub`

Answer (score 0):

This will get you started. It's not perfect

```
Option Explicit
Sub createWorkbooks()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim workbookName As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False       'Overwrite workbooks without alerts
    lastRow = findLastRow("Sheet2", "A:A")  'Get last row of target sheet
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        On Error Resume Next
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Delete  'Remove possible Sheet 1
        On Error GoTo 0
        '*
        '* Create a worksheet template
        '*
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
        ws.Name = "Sheet1"

        Set r = Range("Sheet2!A" & i)
        ws.Range("A1").Value = r.Value      'Copy source cell value to template
        workbookName = r.Value & ".xlsx"    'Set workbook name
        '*
        '* Create a new workbook
        '*
        Set wb = Workbooks.Add
        '*
        '* Copy out newly created template to it
        '*
        ws.Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
        wb.SaveAs workbookName
        wb.Close False
    Next i
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Delete 'Remove last template
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
'*******************************************************
'* Find last used row in a certain sheet
'*
Function findLastRow(Sheetname As String, ColumnName As String) As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim r As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Worksheets(Sheetname)
    lastRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    '*
    '* Search backwards till we find a cell that is not empty
    '*
    Set r = ws.Range(ColumnName).Rows(lastRow)
    While IsEmpty(r)
        Set r = r.Offset(-1, 0)
    Wend
    lastRow = r.Row
    Set ws = Nothing
    findLastRow = lastRow
End Function
```